# How do you open a document from a categorized view in XPages?

Tags: xpages

Is there a trick to opening a document from a categorized view?  I have several categorized views in an Xpage.  In the View custom control of each I have the `Show values in this column as links` checked for the first column after the categorized column, but it doesn't seem to work. When I view the page the column values are not showing as links.

MJ

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the "At runtime, open selected document using:" field on the view properties?

Comment: Post the section of the source for the field, maybe something is just not updating correctly.

Comment: Not sure I get it.  This has been marked answered but according to the comment that answer didn't work...  ??

Comment: I was hoping he would post the code so we could see what was wrong.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I found that I have some configuration issues and that may be causing my problem here. I think I have something out of sync with my extension library, because I can add the application layout to a new xpage and when I try to view it, I get a 404 error, resource not found.  I should at least see an application framework.